# How can I use django to call a python script and return the result in realtime?

Tags: python, django

I am writing a project about managing network devices with django. There is a requirement that running a python script with a button and return the result to the html in realtime.
For example:

views.py:

```
#The script which I want to run
def script():
    print 'wait a minute, programme is running'
    time.sleep(10)
    print 'Now, in progress 1'
    time.sleep(10)
    print 'Now, in progress 2'

#The view which call the script
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       script()
```

I want to put the messages in the html in realtime.How could I implement it ?

Comment: Do you really need to use `print`? It will make it a lot harder/hackier trying to read the stdout

Comment: is the script in a separate python source file?

Comment: @Sayse:No , I can use the stdout.But could you give me an example?Thank you.

Comment: @Pynchia: Yes , it is a separate python souce file

Comment: I'm saying *dont* use the stdout, make actual objects you can actually work with and then the process becomes really trivial. There are a lot of factors you'd be underestimating trying to fudge the stdout

Answer (score 1):

if the script is in a separate python file (e.g. called `script.py`) you can

simply import such module and call the function, if it returns a string as its output

```
import script
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       output = script.script()
       return HttpResponse(output, content_type="text/plain")
```

otherwise, if you need to keep the printouts, launch a separate python process to run it and capture its output

```
import subprocess

def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'script.py'])
       return HttpResponse(output, content_type="text/plain")
```

Have a look at [this subprocess tutorial](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/) on PMOTW

Note1: on Python 3, you might want to convert the output to a string (it's made of bytes)

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'script.py']).decode('utf-8')
```

Note2: it is assumed the process launched does not take too long, otherwise the HTTP request expires and the connection closes.